# How do I read windows pinned folders in golang?

Tags: windows, go

I tried out https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne which implements it's own file handling dialogs.

This means that on all my machines, osx, linux 7 windows my favorites/pinned items go missing when saving; which is a pain.

I See some MSDN articles about the API for this not being fully fleshed out yet, but does anyone know another way to read in golang? Preferably without sub-process calls requiring third-party scripts, or parsing of STDOUT.

I do know that in powershell I can

```
$QuickAccess = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$QuickAccess.Namespace("shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}").Items()
```

Unfortunately I don't know enough about, or have enough experience with powershell to trace this. I Have tried looking at the registry and it seems the values (at least on my machine) are not stored in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Using several third-party resources, I was able to experiment and confirm the location of this file is `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms` and that this seems to be a stable file-name [According to online sources](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/175934-how-backup-restore-quick-access-pinned-folders-windows-10-a.html)

With some googling, from a very slim list of existing materials for reading such a file.

- https://github.com/EricZimmerman/JumpList
- https://github.com/EricZimmerman/OleCf
- https://github.com/richardlehane/mscfb/network
- The file is an OLE serialized document, binary encoded, much like legacy Microsoft office `doc` and `xls` formats.
- I only catered to my own needs, Windows 10, 64-bit.
- I Have not yet added a test-suite, or performed multi-machine verification.
- All the heavy lifting is done by Richard Lehane library

https://github.com/Lewiscowles1986/read-pinned-folders